# Will performing a mongo find in for-loop cause it to crash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a crawler set up that crawls all the (unique)links on a website and stores the links and its body-tag contents in  mongo. Next time I crawl the website, I need to make sure that only new links or links with updated body-tag contents get ingested to avoid duplicates.

So, basically I'm populating an array of freshly crawled links and for each link object in the array I'm performing a
db.collection.find({:link_url = > link_url, :body => body})

Will running the above find query in a for-loop cause any snags or crashes? Let's say at its worst case the array's length might be 5000.

I've tried getting in the whole collection in one query, but that approach requires a deep hash matching and is an n^2 operation. Or it requires multiple hash restructuring operations to make it suitable for comparison.

```
for(i<5000)
  temp = db.collection.find(i) 
end
```

That's the core logic I'm implementing. Is that fine with mongodb/mongoid/rails?

Comment: I do not understand the question, what is stopping you to write the code and test it out?

Comment: I've done load testing. It seems to work fine without any problem. I was wondering if its like a good practice to do something like that in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB will not crash from a large number of queries, however your crawler may run slowly. You may consider using the $in operator to match multiple values in a single query, or $or operator for more complex conditions, and also ensure the queries you are performing are utilizing indexes.